# how I could convert hex to character in groovy?

Tags: groovy, hex, character

convert hex like this feff356f

to character  㕯

I dont know how I could do this in groovy

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
 def hexArr(String str){
    if(str){
       return ([str.take(4)] << hexArr(str.substring(str.size() > 4 ? 4 :str.size()))).flatten().grep()
    } 
 }

 hexArr("feff356f").each{
    println ((char) Integer.parseInt(it, 16))
 }
```

Comment: Nice.  Btw, you can change `hexArr` to: `str ? [str.take(4)] + hexArr(str.drop(4)) : []`